# laravel latest post sort by category

Tags: php, laravel

i have a model setup in Eloquent of a many to many relationship of Pages and Articles. My users have the ability to order these articles per page.

So my question is, can i order the relationship with sync...

```
 $page->articles()->sync($specificOrderOfArticleIds)
```

And it sync the relationships in the order of that passed array.

so when i query the page

```
  $page->articles() // in specified order
```

It's in the specified order.

Maybe i'm missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you'll need some kind of column in the pivot table that defines an order. For example, an "order" column on the pivot table could be given a value using:

```
$page->articles()->sync([1 => ["order" => 1], 42 => ["order" => 6]]);
```

Then on the read, you can pass a closure into your query to specify the order be by this column.

```
$page = Page::whereId($id)->with(['articles' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('pivot.order', 'asc');
}])->get();
```

The "pivot" keyword is used in relationship queries to point to the middle table.

However, you can use the closure ability shown above to order by anything you like, not just the pivot table. Depending on how you define the order, you may not even need the new pivot table column.